# Structuring and pivoting corrupted dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I read from an excel file. The thing is  first 4 columns and its values look good. But after 5th column data seems kind of corrupted.
That is, the "**dateID**" values like "**2021-09-06**" became columns, "**sourceOfData**" column became ""**values**".
And it looks like that:

| countryName | provinceName | productID | productName | dateID | 2021-09-06 | 2021-09-07 | 2021-09-08 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | sourceOfData | productPrice | productPrice | productPrice |
| United States | New York | 35 | Sugar | CommissionAgent1 | 2.6$ | 5.5$ | 3.4$ |
| Canada | Ontario | 55 | Corn | CommissionAgent1 | 2.6$ | 5.5$ | 3.4$ |

But i want my data to look like that:

| countryName | provinceName | productID | productName | sourceOfData | dateID | productPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| United States | New York | 35 | Sugar | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-06 | 2.6$ |
| United States | New York | 35 | Sugar | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-07 | 5.5$ |
| United States | New York | 35 | Sugar | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-08 | 3.4$ |
| Canada | Ontario | 55 | Corn | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-06 | 2.6$ |
| Canada | Ontario | 55 | Corn | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-07 | 5.5$ |
| Canada | Ontario | 55 | Corn | CommissionAgent1 | 2021-09-08 | 3.4$ |

The thing only came to my mind is **pivot** or **melt**. I started doing something like this:

`df2 = df.melt(var_name='dateID', value_name='productPrice')`

`df3 = df2.iloc[1:]`

in order to organize dates and prices, but I'm stuck.

Hope I explained my needs. Thanks in advance.

For those who want to reproduce my question and obtain dataframes, here is the code that consists of what i have and what i need.

```
import pandas as pd

whatIHave = {'countryName': ['','United States','Canada'],
        'provinceName': ['','New York','Ontario'],
        'productID': ['','35','55'],
        'productName': ['', 'Sugar', 'Corn'],
        'dateID': ['sourceOfData', 'CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1'],
        '2021-09-06': ['productPrice','2.6$','2.6$'],
        '2021-09-07': ['productPrice','5.5$','5.5$'],
        '2021-09-08': ['productPrice','3.4$','3.4$']
        }

df_whatIHave = pd.DataFrame(whatIHave, columns = ['countryName', 'provinceName', 'productID', 'productName', 'dateID', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08'])

print(df_whatIHave)


whatINeed = {'countryName': ['United States','United States','United States', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada'],
        'provinceName': ['New York','New York','New York', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Ontario'],
        'productID': ['35','35','35', '55', '55', '55'],
        'productName': ['Sugar', 'Sugar', 'Sugar', 'Corn', 'Corn', 'Corn'],
        'sourceOfData': ['CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1', 'CommissionAgent1'], 
        'dateID': ['2021-09-06', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08'],
        'productPrice': ['2.6$','5.5$','3.4$','2.6$','5.5$','3.4$']
        }

df_whatINeed =  pd.DataFrame(whatINeed, columns = ['countryName', 'provinceName', 'productID', 'productName', 'sourceOfData', 'dateID', 'productPrice'])

print(df_whatINeed)
```

Comment: Use `header=[0,1]` as parameter of `read_excel(...)`

Comment: Tried it, but it's far from the expected result. What I need is to replicate the ```countryName```, ```provinceName```, ```productID```, ```productName``` column values below.  Then I need to add **varied** ```dateID``` and ```productPrice``` values next to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem after hours of searching by dividing the problem into pieces and merging them. If we take into account our dataframe as df_whatIHave:

```
df2 = df_whatIHave.iloc[1:, 0:6]
df2 = df2.reset_index()

columnSize = df_whatIHave.shape[1]

df3 = df_whatIHave.iloc[:, 6:columnSize]
df4 = df3.iloc[1:]
```

I divided my dataframe into 2 parts and implemented **stack()** function which is so crucial for replicating my rows based on date:

```
df4 = df4.stack()
df4 = df4.to_frame().reset_index()
```

Then I merged these two dfs like that:

```
df_merged= pd.merge(df2, df4, on='index', how='inner')
```